# Scope and Lifetime of variables inside "for" loop in c++

Tags: c++, scope, lifetime

why these codes are showing different results :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        static int n = 0;
        n++;
        cout<<n<<endl; // prints 1 2 3 4 5
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        int n = 0;
        n++;
        cout<<n<<endl; // prints 1 1 1 1 1
    }
```

if static variable n is declared again then, why it is retaining its previous value.
What exactly is happening with the scope of static variable inside "for" loop ?
Why does not compiler showed error for declaring again an existing variable, during second iteration in the (first)loop ?

Also please tell why these codes are showing different result :

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        static int n;
        n=0;
        n++;
        cout<<n<<endl; //Print 1 1 1 1 1
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        static int n=0;
        n++;
        cout<<n<<endl; //Print 1 2 3 4 5
    }
```

Comment: " static variable n is declared again then, why it is retaining its previous value" because that's the point of static variable.

Comment: Did you expect them to have the same result? Why?

Comment: Why does not compiler showed error for declaring again an existing variable, during second iteration in the (first)loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable n in the for loop is different from the static one, because their scope is different. If you delete declaration ***int n*** in the if loop you will see output as 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 0):

The name "n" has the same scope in both cases - the loop's body.
(Scope is a property of names, not of objects.)

The first loop has *one* variable, whose lifetime begins at its declaration during the first iteration and ends when the program exits.
The initialisation is only performed when its lifetime begins.

The second loop has a separate variable named "n" for each iteration of the loop.
Their lifetimes begin at the declaration and end when the iteration finishes.